# Is there a way to refer to a parameter in a TypeScript function documentation?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I'm trying to reference parameters in the description of functions like this:

```
/**
 * Deletes the Travel Cost with the given {@param id}
 * @param id the id of the travel cost to be deleted
 */
deleteTravelCost(id: number): Observable<{}> { [...] }
```

But it doesn't seem to work with the `{@param id}`. The result when invoking the function is the following:

```
(method) TravelCostsService.deleteTravelCost(id: number): Observable<{}>

Deletes the Travel Cost with the given {@param id}

@param id — the id of the travel cost to be deleted
```

I expect to have a clickable element in the documentation referencing to the parameter (in the general description of the function, not in the actual parameter description). Is there a proper way to reference a parameter or even the return of a function in the description?
(I'm using Visual Studio Code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @basarat said, there's no way to cross-reference a parameter within documentation itself, so the closest thing to that i can think of is [@link and @see](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#link) directives

```
// this `id` const is referenced only when there's no @param id in doc
const id: number = 33 // or anything
/**
 * Deletes the Travel Cost with the given {@link id}
 * @param id the id of the travel cost to be deleted
 */
deleteTravelCost(id: number): Observable<{}> { [...] }
```

Answer (score 2):

April 2023, VSCode v1.73.1

`{@link paramname}` will be shown as a link in VSCode's annotation popup,
upon clicking it would lead to the referenced parameter.

Example where `@returns` tag contains `@link` parameter references:

```
/**
 * Returns the original collection or filters it before returning
 * @param collection the collection to filter
 * @param filter if `false`, don't filter; otherwise the passed value is a predicate function and will be used for filtering
 * @returns the original {@link collection} with some or all of the original items depending on passed {@link filter}
 */
export function optionalFilter<T>(collection: T[], filter: ((value: T, index?: number, array?: T[]) => boolean) | false) {
    if (filter === false) {
        return collection;
    }
    return collection.filter(filter);
}
```

The VSCode documentation popup looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to properly reference a parameter

You cannot cross reference parameters : https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1145#issue-126426000

> return of a function in the description

Again, you cannot reference it. But you can document it [with returns](https://jsdoc.app/tags-returns.html) e.g.:

```
/**
 * Deletes the Travel Cost with the given 
 * @param id the id of the travel cost to be deleted
 * @returns the result
 */
function deleteTravelCost(id: number): number {
  return id;
}
```

Comment: So, what is the way to go? What is the standard way to reference a parameter?

Comment: @Joserbala, seems that `{@link paramNameHere}` does what was asked if it was possible. And yes, it is. I've tried it with VSCode and it renders as a hyperlink and clicking it jumps to the identifier in the code. It works like `<see />` in C#.